# Automated Deployement Build Failed in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, tomcat8

I am doing automated deployemnt in jenkins and getting error saying that:
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure.

Building on master in workspace:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\AutomatedDeployement1
[AutomatedDeployement1] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins1993620515430909066.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\AutomatedDeployement1>date
The current date is: 08-06-2020 
Enter the new date: (dd-mm-yy) 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\AutomatedDeployement1>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
[DeployPublisher][INFO] Build failed, project not deployed
Finished: FAILURE
```

Your answer will help me in learning. Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

The "marked build as failure" message happens because of the exit code in your batch file. Try `exit 0` instead of `exit 1`.

You can also instruct Jenkins to continue building even though there was a build error.